# Upload large files on google cloud buckets

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload files to my bucket using this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload. I got it working but i can't upload files that are larger than 100 MB. The documentation says you can upload files up to 100 TB.

When I try to upload files larger than 100MB i get a request entity too large error.

Comment: The error message sounds suspicious. Are you uploading directly to Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I had these 2 lines in my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_filesize = 100M
```

Changed it to

```
upload_max_filesize = 100G
post_max_filesize = 100G
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading larger files, you can consider the file to be chunked into small sets of requests that Google App Engine supports.

This package could help - https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload